# jQuery Animate and positioning elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I current have a div that has around 5 images floating left so they are side by side. Now i have this div inside a parent div with overflow:hidden and the width so that it can only fit 4 images in.

Everything works fine apart from the animation, i have two arrows for left and right, but lets say i press right twice it moves across as it would normally but then when i press left once it resets the divs normal position and continues,

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".item_wrap").animate({right: "+=118px"}, 1500 );
    return false;
});
$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(".item_wrap").animate({left: "+=118px"}, 1500 );
    return false;
});
```

this is the code i am currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but lets say i press right twice it moves across as it would normally but then when i press left once it resets the divs normal position and continues

Well that's because you can't animate both `left` and `right` on the same element unless you actually want the element to be stretching (it won't stretch in your case though since you've probably set a static element width.) Instead you animate just one of them by adding and subtracting:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".item_wrap").animate({right: "+=118px"}, 1500 );
    return false;
});
$(".prev").click(function(){
    // Subtract from 'right' instead of adding to 'left'
    $(".item_wrap").animate({right: "-=118px"}, 1500 );
    return false;
});
```